# Satisfy the condition that 'A uniquely determines B' when using Functional Dependencies in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, functional-dependencies

I am trying to write a ‘logger’ Monad Transformer. Other Monad Transformers will then be applied to it, to form a more complex monad. I want the logger function to work on all these monads, so I wrote a typeclass as follows.

```
class Logger e m | m -> e where
    logMessage :: e -> m ()
```

The reason I use Functional Dependencies here, is that the monad `m` will explicitly contain the type `e` (as what it is with `State` monad), which stands for the message type.
The transformer `ET` is made an instance of typeclass Logger.

```
data ET e m a = ET { ... }
instance Monad m => Monad (ET e m) where
    logMessage msg = ...
instance Monad m => Logger e (ET e m) where
    logMessage msg = ...
```

Now, I want the monad `T1 (T2 ... (ET m))` (which has an `ET` in the transformer chain) to be an instance of typeclass `Logger`, but it failed to compile. Below is the code.

```
instance (Logger e m, MonadTrans t) => Logger e (t m) where
    logMessage = lift . logMessage
```

I thought that since `t` is only a Monad Transformer, and `m` is guaranteed to uniquely determine `e`, then `t m` should also uniquely determine `e`. But the compiler seems to think differently.

```
Test.hs:43:10: error:
? Illegal instance declaration for ‘Logger e (t m)’
    The coverage condition fails in class ‘Logger’
      for functional dependency: ‘m -> e’
    Reason: lhs type ‘t m’ does not determine rhs type ‘e’
    Un-determined variable: e
    Using UndecidableInstances might help
? In the instance declaration for ‘MonadException e (t m)’
   |
43 | instance (Logger e m, MonadTrans t) => Logger e (t m) where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Can anyone explain how the extension `FunctionalDependencies` works, as well as how to solve this problem?
The compiler I use is `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.2.2`, on Windows 10.

Comment: Do you actually have UndecidableInstances enabled?  It's almost always necessary with FunctionalDependencie, and the error message suggests you don't.

Comment: @Carl I use FunDeps quite a lot, and I don't think I've never used UndecidableInstances.

Comment: I guess it only comes up when the instances are polymorphic - but that's still an exceptionally common case.  Basically every mtl-style instance, for example.

Comment: @Carl, I am a newbie on such extensions, and someone else had warned me that I had better not enable an extension unless I know exacly what it does, so I just came here to get some suggestions.

Comment: @Krantz That's a good general policy. As an introduction: UndecidableInstances allows you to compile instances with a fully-polymorphic argument. It doesn't break any code that already works, it doesn't allow new bugs.The only downside is that if you have an instance that actually loops during type-checking, it will take longer for the compiler to produce an error message - but it still will. Also, it's usually a bad idea to use it with a single-parameter type class. But for a MPTC with fundeps enabled, it's often necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @Carl, this problem is solved.
When I turned on the language extension **Undecidable Instances** (by `{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}`), this error message disappeared.
Though still I wonder why this extension is needed, for now, it really makes the code compile.

Comment: The reason you need `UndecidableInstances` is that in the instance head `instance ( ... ) => Logger e (t m)` the second parameter is supposed to determine the first, according to the FunDep. But `e` does not appear in `(t m)`. Switching on `UndecidableInstances` in effect says to the compiler "it's OK, the constraints will get you from `(t m)` to `e`". That might or might not be true, the compiler doesn't know. Usually it is OK. But you might try to call method `logMessage` somewhere the compiler can't determine `e`.

Comment: That is not a solution, but a hack that gives you no understanding while introducing a risk that Haskell was specifically designed to avoid. Compare: The `unsafe…` functions. As in: You’re telling the compiler “I know what I’m doing.” when you’re using it precisely because you don’t know what you’re doing. ;) … This will cause unexpected runtime and compilation problems that will be hard to debug in the future. It may still be the right choice, but you should understand why, and what it does, so  you can take precautions against it blowing up in your face later.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that while `m -> e` it doesn't follow that `t m -> e` because the compiler doesn't know anything about what `t` might do.

What you have defined is not actually a monad transformer, its a class of `Logger` monads. Canonically, the [mtl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) way of approaching this would be:

1. Define a `class (Monad m) => MonadLogger e m | m -> e` (just rename your existing class).
2. Define `newtype LoggerT e m a = LoggerT(runLoggerT :: m <...>)`. This is your monad transformer. runLoggerT unwraps a LoggerT action and returns a value in the inner monad `m`. The details of what it returns are up to you.
3. Create instances of `Monad`, `MonadTrans` and `MonadLogger` for `LoggerT`.
4. Define `type Logger e = Logger e Identity`
5. Create inductive instances for all the other mtl monad transformers.

If you take a look at the examples in the mtl library you should be able to see how its done.

Comment: I think I know this method. What I actually want was to automatically make all `t m` (where `t` implements MonadTrans, and `m` implements Logger) an instance of typeclass Logger. Then an explicit `lift` can be omitted. So is it impossible to do this in Haskell?

Comment: @RuifengXie: Sounds like a job for TemplateHaskell… Unfortunately, Haskell sometimes has a surprising lack of generic programming capabilities, and this is a case of that, IMHO. (TemplateHaskell should not even be a thing. It still generates all this very similar code. When, properly done, the commonalities should be abstracted away and be written generically in the language itself.)